# How to implement the "fast inverse square root" with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, optimization

```
fun invSqrt(x: Float): Float {
    var x = x
    val xhalf = 0.5F * x
    var i = java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(x)
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i shr 1)
    x = java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(i)
    x *= 1.5F - xhalf * x * x
    return x
}
```

Is there any shorter or faster way to do this with **Kotlin**?

Comment: You tagged this question with [android]. So you are using Kotlin to develop native android applications abd want to optimize the fast inverse square root for that? Note that a normal inverse square root might be moee performant than a fast inverse square root in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I know :) It's just to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Note that technically, it might be possible to improve the performance of it using Unsafe or Project Panama's Foreign Function and Memory API (especially if you are calculating multiple inverse square roots at the same time) but that's probably bot available in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Doom's fast square root. Which it is a clever way to calculate a extremely close approximate to the inverse square root. I made some changes to make the code a little smaller, but conceptually/algorithmically it will be the same.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.pow

fun fastInverseSqrt(number: Float): Float {
    val i = number.toBits()
    val y = Float.fromBits(0x5f3759df - (i shr 1))
    return y * (1.5F - (number * 0.5F * y * y))
}
```

A video explaining the trickery going on: https://youtu.be/p8u_k2LIZyo

However, the algorithm is considered obsolete now as hardware doesn't have the limitations as it used to have. You might be better of not implementing this method. Check this page for more info in that regard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root